# django-auth-ldap members groups not woking

Tags: django, ldap, openldap, ldap-query, django-auth-ldap

i managed to get ldap authentification working, but the users groups aren't. when a user is autheticated the username, firstname, email ..etc are copied to the session, but the boolean values (gotten from the groups the user belongs to) aren't.

**this is my settings.py :**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]


import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType, GroupOfUniqueNamesType

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://openldap"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "cn=admin,dc=openldap"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "admin"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=django,dc=openldap",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(cn=%(user)s)")

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail",
}

AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 0
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 0
AUTH_LDAP_PROFILE_ATTR_MAP = {"home_directory": "homeDirectory"}
AUTH_LDAP_MIRROR_GROUPS = True
AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True
AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("dc=openldap",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=*)"
)
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType(name_attr='cn')

AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    'is_active': 'cn=active,ou=groups,dc=openldap',
    'is_staff': 'cn=staff,ou=groups,dc=openldap',
    'is_superuser': 'cn=superuser,ou=groups,dc=openldap',
}

# # Simple group restrictions
# AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = 'cn=enabled,ou=groups,dc=openldap',
# AUTH_LDAP_DENY_GROUP = 'cn=disabled,ou=groups,dc=openldap',


### ERROR LOGGING

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('django_auth_ldap')
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

**this is my ldap scheme :**

[image]

root is part of active, staff and superuser.
user1 is part of active.
this is what i get when i authenticate a user from a view:
i get the error -> is not a memeber of

```
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 fd=13 ACCEPT from IP=172.23.0.4:47230 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=0 BIND dn="cn=admin,dc=openldap" method=128
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=0 BIND dn="cn=admin,dc=openldap" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=1 SRCH base="ou=django,dc=openldap" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(cn=root)"
openldap        | 5b444c1f <= mdb_equality_candidates: (cn) not indexed
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
django          | search_s('ou=django,dc=openldap', 2, '(cn=%(user)s)') returned 1 objects: cn=root,ou=django,dc=openldap
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=2 BIND anonymous mech=implicit ssf=0
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=2 BIND dn="cn=root,ou=django,dc=openldap" method=128
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=2 BIND dn="cn=root,ou=django,dc=openldap" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=2 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
django          | Populating Django user root
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=3 BIND anonymous mech=implicit ssf=0
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=3 BIND dn="cn=admin,dc=openldap" method=128
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=3 BIND dn="cn=admin,dc=openldap" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=3 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=4 CMP dn="cn=active,ou=groups,dc=openldap" attr="member"
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=4 RESULT tag=111 err=16 text=
django          | cn=root,ou=django,dc=openldap is not a member of cn=active,ou=groups,dc=openldap
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=5 CMP dn="cn=staff,ou=groups,dc=openldap" attr="member"
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=5 RESULT tag=111 err=16 text=
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=6 CMP dn="cn=superuser,ou=groups,dc=openldap" attr="member"
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=6 RESULT tag=111 err=16 text=
django          | cn=root,ou=django,dc=openldap is not a member of cn=staff,ou=groups,dc=openldap
django          | cn=root,ou=django,dc=openldap is not a member of cn=superuser,ou=groups,dc=openldap
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=7 SRCH base="dc=openldap" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=*)(member=cn=root,ou=django,dc=openldap))"
openldap        | 5b444c1f <= mdb_equality_candidates: (member) not indexed
openldap        | 5b444c1f conn=1015 op=7 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=0 text=
django          | search_s('dc=openldap', 2, '(&(objectClass=*)(member=cn=root,ou=django,dc=openldap))') returned 0 objects:
```

PS: the user is autheticated without a problem but when i print `user.is_staff`, `user.is_active` and `user.is_superuser` i get `False` for all of them.

Comment: anybody ? has an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a few years late to reply but I stumbled on your question when I was trying to solve my own issues getting `django-auth-ldap` working with my AD server.

From your logs, I can see a few messages like this:

```
django          | cn=root,ou=django,dc=openldap is not a member of cn=superuser,ou=groups,dc=openldap
```

What solved the problem for me was the following quote from [here](https://github.com/django-auth-ldap/django-auth-ldap/issues/138#issuecomment-631638905):

> If your filter is too specific, groups in the middle will be
> overlooked, leading to a incomplete group list.
>
> Dont make your filter too specific. It doesnt matter too much anyway,
> since the groups will only be returned if the user belongs to them,
> even indirectly.

While specifically NOT applicable to your case, and possibly inverse of your scenario: *I think that is the crux of your problem*. `django-auth-ldap` can't find your groups. I think you are starting way at the root which is the DC. Try changing your `AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH` to be a bit more specific like the following to see if that helps:

```
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
    "OU=groups,DC=openldap",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    "(objectClass=group)",
)
```

I'm not an expert at LDAP / AD by any means so YMMV.